# How to check support for Ultrawide 1440p?

Tags: display, hdmi, external-display

I have MSI GF75 Thin 10SC and I wanted to buy an ultrawide monitor with 3440x1440p.

As per the specs my laptop supports 4K at 30hz. So if I go with the above resolution will it support ultrawide with 60hz?

The specs are: Core i5 10300H with GTX 1650. There’s no display port and the USB C also doesn’t support display. Only HDMI is the option.

Answer (score 0):

Using Windows?

On Linux there is an `nvidia-settings` app,
check if you have a corresponding one available ...
and what it tells you.

**Approximate requirement:**
3440 * 1440 => 4953600 pixels
(multipily by) 4 bytes per pixel => 19,814,400 bytes
(multipily by) 60 as it is to be read at 60 Hz => 1,188,864,000 bytes/second
(divide by 1024²) to get "megabytes" -> 1133 MB/s (megabyte per second)
(multipily by 8) as each byte has 8 bits -> 9070 Mbits to read per second.

Does your application tell about a memory transfer rate that is higher than 9000 MHz?
*(The Linux nvidia-settings does)*
If yes, then the 3440x1440 -screen mode should be possible.

*NOTE / Warning: The above is based entirely on logic reasoning, nothing else.*

Answer (score 0):

Use the NVIDIA Control Panel to create the resolution you want.

When adding a new custom resolution, it will check that the new mode
is safe. If safe, the notification is of a successful addition of that mode.
If not safe, the notification will say that.

This is done in the NVIDIA Control Panel, "Display" branch, screen
"Change resolution", using the "Customize..." button.

Comment: I don't have the monitor yet. So I can check for the above resolution on my laptop display itself?

Comment: Try it and see... Even if it doesn't work, perhaps the message itself will be useful.

Comment: Bad luck. i don't have any setting that says Change resolution in Nvidia Control Panel

Comment: Your card (and software) is then different than mine. Try the [Custom Resolution Utility (CRU)](https://www.monitortests.com/forum/Thread-Custom-Resolution-Utility-CRU).